# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'.' when retrieving SQL table data using EF

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, binary

This is my entity

[image: entity].

I have a SQL table that I'm trying to display in a view as a table using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC.

Three of the columns are of data type binary(32) and I am having difficulties getting the right property type for them in my entity model. Currently getting a casting error when retrieving them in my Linq query in the controller.

How can I model and convert a SQL column of type `binary(32)` so I can display it on a view for customers to see it?

[image: Design]

[image: Table]

[image: Controller error]

Comment: The .Net type corresponding to `binary(32)` is `byte[]`.  But that's an odd database type for IDs.

Comment: I did try using a byte[] and got this error:  The property 'AdvisorRecommendation.AssessmentID' could not be mapped because it is of type 'byte?[]', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: `byte?[]` is an array of `Nullable<byte>`.  That's a different type and not what you need.  What version of EF?  Can you post a simple repro if you're still getting this with `byte[]`.  And what's the deal with 32-byte binary IDs?  Perhaps there's a better .NET type you can map  to with a ValueConversion.

Comment: If i remove ? i.e nullable I get: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.' Currently on EF 6. Basically I need to turn those columns into hexadecimals some how.

Comment: EF6 or EF Core 6?  And, no you can't have that be null.  You'd have to set a value in the EF client.

Comment: I dont understand why I got -1 on this one, my question is simple and clear? EF6 Core.

Comment: Probably for posting pictures of code instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

`byte[]` is a nullable type.  `byte?[]` is a nullable array of nullable bytes.  It's not useful here.

You can use a nullable `byte[]` as your key so long as you add a `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` decoration to specify that the database will generate the value.  EG:

```
builder.Entity<AdvisorRecommendation>()
       .Property(e => e.Id)
       .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
       .HasDefaultValueSql("newid()");
```

But it's still odd to use `binary(32)` for your keys.